# How to disable all the date which have no events in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have used this code but it is not working to disable dates with out event,here in this code there will be dates which will be available but some dates blank which is clickable, if i click on it is showing one popup i have created but color is turning into green which is not required please check it

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
    },
    views: {
        month: {
            titleFormat: 'YYYY, MM, DD'
        }
    },

    validRange: function(nowDate) {
        return {
            start: nowDate,
            end: nowDate.clone().add(2, 'months')
        };
    },

    navLinks: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end) {
        startDate = moment(new Date(start)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
        endDate = moment(new Date(end)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
            start: start,
            end: end,
            rendering: 'background',
            block: true,
        }]);

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    selectOverlap: function(event) {
        return !event.block;
    },

    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
        if (!IsDateHasEvent(date)) {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-disabled-day disabled');
        }
    },

    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,

    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/my-url',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                tutor_id: $('#tutor_id').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var events = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var start = response[i]['tutor_start_date'] + ' ' + response[i]['tutor_start_time'];
                    var end = response[i]['tutor_start_date'] + ' ' + response[i]['tutor_end_time'];

                    events.push({
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        color: '#8ec165',
                        tutor_id: response[i]['tutor_id'],
                        id: response[i]['id'],
                        textColor: 'white'
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    },

    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        startDate = moment(new Date(event.start)).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
        endDate = moment(new Date(event.end)).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
        var startEndDate = startDate + ',' + endDate;

        slected_date_arr.push(startEndDate);
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(slected_date_arr);
        $('#selected_date_times').val(myJsonString);
    },
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        if (!IsDateHasEvent(date)) {
            selectedDate = date;
            // $("#divAddNewAppointment").dialog("open");
            alert('This date is not available for selection');
            return false;
        } else {
            // $('<%= "#" + lblMessage.ClientID%>').html(" your error msg");
            // $("#divMessage").dialog("open");
            console.log('there is event');
            return true;
        }
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: '<b> Time -' + event.start.format('hh:mma') + ' - ' + event.end.format('hh:mma') + '</b>',
        });
    },

    eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
        $(".fc-time-grid-event").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('background-color', '#B7A6EE');
            $(this).css('border-color', '#B7A6EE');

            $(this).removeClass("fc-time-grid-event").addClass("selected-event");
            var quantity = $('.selected-event').length;
            $("#quantity").val(quantity);

            var totalQuantity = $("#quantity").val();
            var tutorAmount = {
                {
                    $tutor_price
                }
            };
            var totalAmount = totalQuantity * tutorAmount;
            $("#payable_amount").html(totalAmount);
            $("#coursePrice").val(totalAmount);
        });

        $(".fc-day-grid-event").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('background-color', '#B7A6EE');
            $(this).css('border-color', '#B7A6EE');

            $(this).removeClass("fc-day-grid-event").addClass("selected-event");
            var quantity = $('.selected-event').length;
            $("#quantity").val(quantity);

            var totalQuantity = $("#quantity").val();
            var tutorAmount = {
                {
                    $tutor_price
                }
            };
            var totalAmount = totalQuantity * tutorAmount;
            $("#payable_amount").html(totalAmount);
            $("#coursePrice").val(totalAmount);
        });
    },

});
```

Definition for IsDateHasEvent()

```
function IsDateHasEvent(date) {
   var allEvents = [];
   allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
   var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
   return +v.start === +date;
   });
   return event.length > 0;
}
```

This calendar is displaying to students, so I want them to select only available slots.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan you can already see the OP's attempt above

Comment: I don't know what your "IsDateHasEvent()" function does (or exactly what is going wrong - "not working" doesn't tell me if you have an error, or some kind of unexpected behaviour, or where your debugging has indicated that either of those is occurring), but I predict that this will fail because at the time the day is rendered, events have not been added to the calendar yet, so you can't detect it

Comment: I would like to ask why you want to do this? What do you hope to achieve by disabling all days which have no events? I can't figure out how this would be useful.

Comment: @ADyson i have edited my question

Comment: Ok thanks. As I suspected, this will never be successful because the dayRender function runs before any events are added to the calendar

Comment: Now, if you're using events to indicate available slots, then I think you're going about it the wrong way. That's not how fullCalendar is intended to be used. Events should be used to indicate slots which are already booked, and are no longer available. To indicate available times you can use [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/businessHours), and combine it with [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectConstraint) to actually restrict where the user can click to create an event.

Comment: N.B. if the businessHours format is too rigid (e.g. you need more variations per day, or per week or whatever), then you could consider instead using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/background-events) combined with [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/selectOverlap) to implement the same idea.

Comment: @ADyson I'm new to this fullcalendar I couldn't achieve your above solution, i have edited my post with complete code.

Comment: I made a demo using just the selection code from your code above: http://jsfiddle.net/d59gq8up/ . In your code, if you drag to select an area of time, it creates a background event in that area. Then afterwards if you try to select the same area again, you can't, because it's already taken.

Comment: However, my suggestion was the opposite of that. You need to pre-populate the calendar (from your server, via AJAX) with background events which represent the _available_ times. Then you need to make it so that the event can only be created if it _does_ overlap a background event, not if it _doesn't_.

Comment: P.S. if you are new to fullCalendar, I would recommend perhaps learning the new version 4, instead of this version 3 code. It's likely to be supported for longer and get more new features, but the way you use it is quite different from v3. Code samples, documentation, demos, upgrade information etc are all available on the fullCalendar website.

Comment: @ADyson can I disable the date on rendering first time?

Comment: Yes, if you make these background events part of your `events` feed, and implement the overlap rule correctly (there's actually an example in the selectOverlap documentation page).